# LSTM not converging

Tags: lstm, pytorch, convergence

I am sorry if this questions is basic but I am quite new to NN in general. I am trying to build an LSTM to predict certain properties of a light curve (the output is 0 or 1). I build it in pytorch. Here is my code:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.optim as optim
import numpy as np

torch.manual_seed(1)
torch.cuda.set_device(0)

from fastai.learner import *

n_hidden = 64
n_classes = 2
bs = 1

class TESS_LSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, nl):
        super().__init__()
        self.nl = nl
        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(1, n_hidden, nl, dropout=0.01, bidirectional=True)
        self.l_out = nn.Linear(n_hidden*2, n_classes)
        self.init_hidden(bs)

    def forward(self, input):
        outp,h = self.rnn(input.view(len(input), bs, -1), self.h)
        #self.h = repackage_var(h)
        return F.log_softmax(self.l_out(outp),dim=2)

    def init_hidden(self, bs):
        self.h = (V(torch.zeros(self.nl*2, bs, n_hidden)),
                  V(torch.zeros(self.nl*2, bs, n_hidden)))

model = TESS_LSTM(2).cuda()
loss_function = nn.NLLLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

for epoch in range(50):
    model.zero_grad()
    tag_scores = model(data_x)
    loss = loss_function(tag_scores.reshape(len(data_x),n_classes), data_y.reshape(len(data_y)))
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    if epoch%10==0:
        print("Loss at epoch %d = " %epoch, loss)
```

Also:

```py
data_x = tensor([
    [0.9995450377],
    [0.9991207719],
    [0.9986526966],
    [1.0017241240],
    [1.0016067028],
    [1.0000480413],
    [1.0016841888],
    [1.0010652542],
    [0.9991232157],
    [1.0004128218],
    [0.9986800551],
    [1.0011130571],
    [1.0001415014],
    [1.0004080534],
    [1.0016922951],
    [1.0008358955],
    [1.0001622438],
    [1.0004277229],
    [1.0011759996],
    [1.0013391972],
    [0.9995799065],
    [1.0019282103],
    [1.0006642342],
    [1.0006272793],
    [1.0011570454],
    [1.0015332699],
    [1.0011225939],
    [1.0003337860],
    [1.0014277697],
    [1.0003565550],
    [0.9989787340],
    [1.0006136894],
    [1.0003052950],
    [1.0001049042],
    [1.0020918846],
    [0.9999115467],
    [1.0006635189],
    [1.0007561445],
    [1.0016170740],
    [1.0008252859],
    [0.9997656345],
    [1.0001330376],
    [1.0017272234],
    [1.0004107952],
    [1.0012439489],
    [0.9994274378],
    [1.0014992952],
    [1.0015807152],
    [1.0004781485],
    [1.0010997057],
    [1.0011326075],
    [1.0005493164],
    [1.0014353991],
    [0.9990324974],
    [1.0012129545],
    [0.9990709424],
    [1.0006347895],
    [1.0000327826],
    [1.0005196333],
    [1.0012207031],
    [1.0003460646],
    [1.0004434586],
    [1.0003618002],
    [1.0005420446],
    [1.0005528927],
    [1.0006977320],
    [1.0005317926],
    [1.0000808239],
    [1.0005664825],
    [0.9994245768],
    [0.9999254942],
    [1.0011985302],
    [1.0009841919],
    [0.9999029040],
    [1.0014100075],
    [1.0014085770],
    [1.0005567074],
    [1.0016088486],
    [0.9997186661],
    [0.9998687506],
    [0.9988344908],
    [0.9999858141],
    [1.0004914999],
    [1.0003308058],
    [1.0001890659],
    [1.0002681017],
    [1.0029908419],
    [1.0005286932],
    [1.0004363060],
    [0.9994311333],
    [1.0011523962],
    [1.0008679628],
    [1.0014137030],
    [0.9994244576],
    [1.0003470182],
    [1.0001592636],
    [1.0002418756],
    [0.9992931485],
    [1.0016175508],
    [1.0000959635],
    [1.0005099773],
    [1.0008889437],
    [0.9998087287],
    [0.9995828867],
    [0.9997566342],
    [1.0002474785],
    [1.0010808706],
    [1.0002821684],
    [1.0013456345],
    [1.0013040304],
    [1.0010949373],
    [1.0002720356],
    [0.9996811152],
    [1.0006061792],
    [1.0012511015],
    [0.9999302626],
    [0.9985374212],
    [1.0002642870],
    [0.9996038675],
    [1.0007606745],
    [0.9992995858],
    [1.0000385046],
    [0.9997834563],
    [1.0005996227],
    [1.0006167889],
    [1.0015753508],
    [1.0010306835],
    [0.9997833371],
    [1.0010590553],
    [1.0008200407],
    [1.0008001328],
    [1.0014072657],
    [0.9994395375],
    [0.9991182089],
    [1.0011717081],
    [1.0007920265],
    [1.0011025667],
    [1.0004047155],
    [1.0017303228],
    [1.0014981031],
    [0.9995774031],
    [0.9999650121],
    [0.9992966652],
    [1.0013586283],
    [1.0003392696],
    [1.0005040169],
    [1.0008341074],
    [1.0014744997],
    [0.9996585250],
    [1.0019916296],
    [1.0007069111],
    [1.0004591942],
    [1.0004271269],
    [0.9991059303],
    [1.0003436804],
    [0.9990482330],
    [0.9980322123],
    [0.9980198145],
    [0.9966595173],
    [0.9969686270],
    [0.9977232814],
    [0.9969192147],
    [0.9962794185],
    [0.9947851300],
    [0.9946336746],
    [0.9943053722],
    [0.9946651459],
    [0.9930071235],
    [0.9940539598],
    [0.9950682521],
    [0.9947031140],
    [0.9950703979],
    [0.9945428371],
    [0.9945927858],
    [0.9937841296],
    [0.9944553375],
    [0.9929991364],
    [0.9940859079],
    [0.9930059314],
    [0.9942978621],
    [0.9950152636],
    [0.9943225384],
    [0.9934711456],
    [0.9929080606],
    [0.9934846163],
    [0.9954113960],
    [0.9925802350],
    [0.9929560423],
    [0.9933584929],
    [0.9929228425],
    [0.9930893779],
    [0.9936142564],
    [0.9943635464],
    [0.9933300614],
    [0.9925817847],
    [0.9927681088],
    [0.9930697680],
    [0.9937900901],
    [0.9919354320],
    [0.9937084913],
    [0.9951301217],
    [0.9926426411],
    [0.9933566451],
    [0.9937180877],
    [0.9922621250],
    [0.9933888316],
    [0.9936477542],
    [0.9916112423],
    [0.9943441153],
    [0.9934164286],
    [0.9949553013],
    [0.9941871166],
    [0.9933763146],
    [0.9959306121],
    [0.9930690527],
    [0.9928541183],
    [0.9936354756],
    [0.9931223392],
    [0.9936516881],
    [0.9935654402],
    [0.9932218790],
    [0.9943401814],
    [0.9931038022],
    [0.9926875830],
    [0.9928631186],
    [0.9936705232],
    [0.9939361215],
    [0.9942125678],
    [0.9939611554],
    [0.9936586618],
    [0.9933990240],
    [0.9948219061],
    [0.9940339923],
    [0.9950091243],
    [0.9952197671],
    [0.9947227240],
    [0.9935435653],
    [0.9956403971],
    [0.9943848252],
    [0.9942221045],
    [0.9960014224],
    [0.9931004643],
    [0.9960579872],
    [0.9951166511],
    [0.9964768291],
    [0.9968702793],
    [0.9967978597],
    [0.9971982837],
    [0.9977793097],
    [0.9982623458],
    [0.9988413453],
    [1.0008778572],
    [1.0013417006],
    [1.0000336170],
    [0.9979853630],
    [0.9988892674],
    [0.9994396567],
    [1.0002176762],
    [1.0017417669],
    [1.0013097525],
    [1.0011264086],
    [1.0004124641],
    [1.0003939867],
    [0.9996479750],
    [0.9995540380],
    [1.0003930330],
    [1.0016323328],
    [1.0004589558],
    [0.9996963739],
    [0.9989817142],
    [0.9998068213],
    [1.0011200905],
    [1.0006275177],
    [1.0000452995],
    [1.0012514591],
    [1.0002357960],
    [0.9993159175],
    [1.0002738237],
    [0.9994575381],
    [0.9986617565],
    [0.9982920289],
    [0.9998571873],
    [0.9996472597],
    [1.0012613535],
    [1.0015693903],
    [0.9999635220],
    [1.0006184578],
    [1.0010757446],
    [0.9988756776],
    [1.0004955530],
    [1.0011548996],
    [1.0007628202],
    [1.0006260872],
    [0.9989725947],
    [1.0013129711],
    [0.9994829297],
    [0.9998571873],
    [0.9994959831],
    [1.0007432699],
    [0.9995724559],
    [0.9999076724],
    [0.9992097020],
    [1.0011855364],
    [0.9987785220],
    [1.0010210276],
    [0.9998293519],
    [0.9996315837],
    [0.9999501705],
    [1.0001417398],
    [1.0005141497],
    [0.9993781447],
    [1.0003532171],
    [0.9999422431],
    [1.0014258623],
    [1.0012118816],
    [0.9994109273],
    [1.0019438267],
    [1.0012354851],
    [1.0009905100],
    [1.0001032352],
    [0.9999653101],
    [0.9991906881],
    [1.0004152060],
    [0.9998226762],
    [0.9999175668],
    [0.9994540215],
    [1.0000722408],
    [1.0019129515],
    [0.9997307658],
    [0.9996227026],
    [1.0011816025],
    [0.9993667006],
    [1.0010036230],
    [0.9993645549],
    [1.0004647970],
    [0.9995272160],
    [0.9989504814],
    [0.9981039166],
    [1.0006005764],
    [0.9998896718],
    [1.0004893541],
    [0.9991874099],
    [1.0005015135],
    [0.9995905161],
    [0.9990965128],
    [1.0012912750],
    [1.0004948378],
    [1.0002779961],
    [0.9988743067],
    [1.0019037724],
    [1.0006437302],
    [0.9999380112],
    [1.0001602173],
    [0.9997741580],
    [0.9988395572],
    [0.9999371171],
    [0.9989091754],
    [0.9987531900],
    [1.0003957748],
    [0.9997722507],
    [0.9988819361],
    [0.9998422265],
    [0.9986129999],
    [0.9989410639],
    [1.0016149282],
    [0.9997441173],
    [1.0002747774],
    [0.9990793467],
    [1.0006495714],
    [1.0004252195],
    [0.9997921586],
    [0.9987344146],
    [0.9998763800],
    [0.9988097548],
    [1.0007627010],
    [1.0004670620],
    [1.0007309914],
    [0.9987894297],
    [1.0000542402],
    [1.0004990101],
    [0.9999514818],
    [0.9998412132],
    [1.0000183582],
    [1.0003197193],
    [0.9991712570],
    [0.9992188215],
    [0.9986482859],
    [1.0010583401],
    [1.0011837482],
    [0.9993829727],
    [0.9995718002],
    [0.9997168183],
    [1.0017461777],
    [0.9998381138],
    [0.9990652204],
    [1.0001449585],
    [0.9998424053],
    [1.0011798143],
    [1.0013160706],
    [0.9995942712],
    [1.0001651049],
    [1.0001466274],
    [0.9982855320],
    [0.9992064238],
    [1.0009102821],
    [0.9982813597],
    [1.0000503063],
    [0.9982630014],
    [1.0017516613],
    [0.9995808005],
    [0.9989835620],
    [1.0003046989],
    [1.0019340515],
    [0.9996930957],
    [1.0000711679],
    [1.0011881590],
    [1.0009138584],
    [1.0013902187],
    [0.9994105101],
    [0.9986224174],
    [0.9995336533],
    [1.0006912947],
    [0.9995169044],
    [0.9998968840],
    [0.9989182949],
    [0.9999300838],
    [0.9991120696],
    [0.9996063709],
    [1.0008803606],
    [1.0019868612],
    [1.0004760027],
    [0.9996407032],
    [1.0011100769],
    [1.0026890039],
    [0.9996611476],
    [0.9991108775],
    [0.9982090592],
    [1.0000833273],
    [1.0015701056],
    [0.9994426966],
    [0.9999341369],
    [1.0002813339],
    [0.9998958707],
    [1.0011670589],
    [1.0009137392],
    [0.9994600415],
    [1.0010378361],
    [1.0008393526],
    [1.0013997555],
    [0.9994245768],
    [0.9995403886],
    [0.9997746348],
    [0.9997846484],
    [1.0012620687],
    [1.0009645224],
    [0.9995513558],
    [1.0008162260],
    [1.0008013248],
    [0.9990139604],
    [1.0004394054],
    [0.9991726875],
    [1.0009342432],
    [1.0008635521],
    [1.0007735491],
    [1.0013785362],
    [0.9997245073],
    [0.9989474416],
    [0.9996470809],
    [1.0008428097],
    [1.0017400980],
    [0.9994468689],
    [0.9999369979],
    [1.0007227659],
    [1.0012919903],
    [0.9981160164],
    [0.9999316335],
    [0.9997596741],
    [1.0008264780],
    [0.9994930029],
    [1.0001339912],
    [0.9998437166],
    [0.9999112487],
    [1.0001872778],
    [1.0006663799],
    [1.0007426739],
    [1.0016776323],
    [0.9996471405],
    [0.9981047511],
    [1.0007015467],
    [1.0006203651],
    [0.9987628460],
    [0.9981441498],
    [0.9981172085],
    [0.9999507666],
    [1.0002735853],
    [1.0006685257],
    [1.0001268387],
    [1.0000184774],
    [0.9998023510],
    [1.0006322861]], device='cuda:0')
```

and

```py
data_y = tensor([
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [1],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0]
    ], device='cuda:0')
```

I read data_x and data_y from a file, so that's why I just pasted the values here. See the image below: 0 corresponds to blue and 1 to red.

And this is the output:

```
Loss at epoch 0 =  tensor(0.6795, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
Loss at epoch 10 =  tensor(0.4872, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
Loss at epoch 20 =  tensor(0.4818, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
Loss at epoch 30 =  tensor(0.4834, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
Loss at epoch 40 =  tensor(0.4828, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
```

I tried reducing and increasing the learning rate, trying SGD and RMSprop increasing the number of epochs, but the loss always stops at 0.48. This is part of the output of `model(data_x)`:

```py
tensor([[[-0.3617, -1.1924]],

        [[-0.3046, -1.3373]],

        [[-0.2696, -1.4424]],

        [[-0.2477, -1.5169]],

        [[-0.2345, -1.5654]],

        [[-0.2262, -1.5971]],
```

And all the other values are similar to this. I expected at least that the LSTM will overfit my model, or at least predict 0 for everything (given that I have just few ones, the loss would still be pretty small). But instead it just predicts these numbers and I am not sure why it stops there. I tried any debugging method I know (which are not very many given my AI experience). How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Can you print out data_x.size() and data_y.size()?

Comment: @ArmenAghajanyan this is the output for both: torch.Size([500, 1]) The size of the vectors is the right one needed by the PyTorch LSTM. I actually tried replacing all the ones in the output with zeros (so all the outputs are zeros), and in that case the loss goes down to 10^-5, so the LSTM seems to be able to learn in general, it just has a problem in this case (actually even if I have only one "1" and the rest zeros, it also stops learning).

Comment: Instead of using 2 outputs followed by log_softmax trained with NLL, use 1 output followed sigmoid and trained with binary_cross_entropy